# Android 420 dpi and 560dpi

Tags: android, drawable, screen-density

Is there a way to create a drawable folder and a values folder to 420 dpi and 560 dpi devices? One for the 420 dpi and one for 560 dpi.

420dpi: Samsung Galaxy S5, S4, LG G5, ...

560dpi: Nexus 6, Samsung S6, S7, ...

Because in those type of devices my app not looks well. Images in drawable-xxhdpi are smaller in a device with 420 dpi. Because multiplies the width of the image x 2,625 (density). I need bigger images or multiply images x 3.

Comment: So have you tried xxxhdpi? https://material.io/devices/ and https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2014/10/getting-your-apps-ready-for-nexus-6-and.html

Comment: Use Vector Drawables that can scale well

Comment: Yes i have a values-xxxhdpi. In a device with 560 dpi the image is smaller than a device with density xxxhdpi

Comment: @cricket_007 what is Vector Drawables

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/material/drawables.html

Comment: This is not what i am looking

Answer (score 6):

The solution that I've found is to create a drawable-420dpi and a drawable-560dpi folder and copy xxhdpi and xxxhdpi resources respectively.

I'm not sure that this is the best solution but It works on PIXEL XL, Nexus 5X, 6 and 6p simulators.

This is very frustrating for developers and designers too.

Comment: How about density ABI splits for those (420 and 560) - I've tried all combinations and searched for information but found none!?

Answer (score 2):

If you using Android Studio, you can easily create a folder width name: mipmap-420dpi and mipmap-560dpi in the folder that same with folders as mipmap-hdpi, mipmap-mdpi, mipmap-xhdpi .... You can see [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ct6v.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can get ppi using DisplayMetrics and after getting ppi you can use IF condition and set that drawable that you need to set.

Comment: is not another easy way to do it?

Comment: Sadly, There is no other way I think.

Comment: I need also to change position